# How to get the same result without IFNULL - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I made sqlfiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bbb6d/1/0

```
    SELECT
        `Image`.`id`,
        `Topic`.`title`
    FROM
        `images` AS `Image`, `topics` AS `Topic`
    WHERE
        `Image`.`vender_id` = 'model' AND `Topic`.`id` = IFNULL((SELECT article_id FROM articles_images WHERE image_id = `Image`.`id` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1), 999)
    ORDER BY
        `Image`.`id` DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

Result:   (CORRECT)

```
id  title
8   
7   
5   CCC
4   DDD
3   BBB
2   BBB
1
```

Without `IFNULL(..., 999)` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bbb6d/2

Result:

```
id  title
5   CCC
4   DDD
3   BBB
2   BBB
```

But I also need records with empty "**title**" => id: 8, 7 and 1

Is there a way to have all records without using **IFNULL**?

+++ UPDATED +++

@Used_By_Already

Thank you for your help.
I got result:   (It has two records with ID:5)

```
id  title
8   (null)
7   (null)
5   AAA              << X
5   CCC              << correct 
4   DDD
3   BBB
2   BBB
1   (null)
```

There are two records with the same **ID**: 5, how can I get only one of them that is highest by **articles_images.id**?

Result that I need to get is:

```
id  title
8   
7   
5   CCC
4   DDD
3   BBB
2   BBB
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left joins:

```
SELECT
     I.id
    ,T.title
FROM images AS i
LEFT JOIN articles_images AS ai ON I.id = ai.image_id
LEFT JOIN topics AS t on ai.article_id = t.id
WHERE i.vender_id = 'model' 
ORDER BY
    i.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The result of this is slightly different than your requested result:

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  8 | NULL  |
|  7 | NULL  |
|  5 | AAA   |
|  5 | CCC   |
|  4 | DDD   |
|  3 | BBB   |
|  2 | BBB   |
|  1 | NULL  |
+----+-------+
```

for the RE-modified question (including NULLs):

```
SELECT
     I.id
    ,max(T.title) as title
FROM images AS i
LEFT JOIN articles_images AS ai ON I.id = ai.image_id
LEFT JOIN topics AS t on ai.article_id = t.id
WHERE i.vender_id = 'model' 
GROUP BY
     I.id
;

+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | NULL  |
|  2 | BBB   |
|  3 | BBB   |
|  4 | DDD   |
|  5 | CCC   |
|  7 | NULL  |
|  8 | NULL  |
+----+-------+
```

see:  https://rextester.com/LCOBW94449

---

To guarantee you are using the highest article_if I suggest this:

```
SELECT
     I.id
    ,T.title
FROM ximages AS i
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT image_id, max(article_id) article_id
            FROM xarticles_images
            GROUP BY image_id
          ) AS ai ON I.id = ai.image_id
LEFT JOIN xtopics AS t on ai.article_id = t.id
WHERE i.vender_id = 'model' 
ORDER BY
    i.id DESC
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I edit my question, can you please give it a look?

Comment: "modified question" it works great, but I also need records with "NULL" titles. It's probably hard to combine them together

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't change the question, sorry if make confused

Comment: Yes you made me confused.  Use the `LEFT JOINs` the answer has been changed

Comment: plus one, thank you very much for your patience and help. It works perfectly. I wish I could buy you a beer ^^
"To guarantee you are using the highest article_if I suggest this:" that what I was looking for. Thank you very much man

Comment: one more version added... to ensure you use highest article_id.  I will have that beer :)  let me know which city & I may find you one day perhaps, Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

use left join

```
      SELECT
        i.`id`,
        t.`title`
    FROM
        `images` AS i left join `topics` AS  t on  i.`vender_id` = 'model' 
         and t.`id`=i.article_id
```

Comment: This sql has syntax error and can get an upvote? Check `and on`

Comment: Have you run your sql in the jsfiddle? It still won't work!